# "direction" to describe quality of movie directing?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

E.g., you can say:

> man, that flick's cinematography left much to be desired...

to express that the director of photography did a poor job.

What do you say when you want to talk about *the* director? I must say I haven't heard many (if any) people say *"the direction of this movie was good."*

Even though it [*can* be used that way](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/direction), it doesn't seem in wide use. Is there a better single word expression for this?

edit: What I'm looking for is not rephrasing, and not necessarily something you'll use in spoken, day-to-day english (although it can be) -- more like I'm looking for a term that can be even a bit technical (and used in written/technical/formal English), yet still pretty unambiguous. E.g. *direction*'s meaning is pretty unclear, while *cinematography*'s meaning is more obvious (albeit it can be bit ambiguous, too).

Comment: **Direction** does not describe **quality**. It is simply a noun, a name for the action of the director.

Comment: Bad wording in the title I guess - I didn't mean it it itself describes it, just as a referent, hence the link to merriam-webster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say "That was  great **directing**!"

Compare *[The Director's Idea: The Path to Great Directing](https://books.google.com/books?id=SXfWkXHDJpUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22great%20directing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_z_G8xIvVAhWLGT4KHf4kBnYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22great%20directing%22&f=false)* by Ted Dancyger.